# Why is MySQL Command Line Client rejecting my statement when Workbench is fine with it?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, command-line-interface

I have a list of SQL queries I need the log output of, so I'm using the MySQL Command Line Client. All of them produce the correct output except the following query, which throws a syntax error. The purpose of the query is to get the CustID of the customer who has ordered the largest total quantity of products. I'm using subqueries but maybe this is wrong:

```
SELECT CUSTNUM FROM(
  SELECT CUSTNUM, MAX(TOTALQTY) FROM(
    SELECT CUSTNUM, SUM(QTY) AS TOTALQTY
    FROM ORDERS GROUP BY CUSTNUM ORDER BY TOTALQTY DESC
    ) ORDERS
  ) ORDERS;
```

...I get this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'ORDERS GROUP BY CUSTNUM ORDER BY TOTALQTY DESC) ORDERS    ) ORDERS' at 
line 1
```

I don't understand why this query is working fine in Workbench but not in the command line.

Comment: What does `doesn't work` mean?

Comment: Damn, forgot to post error message, one sec

Comment: Your error isn't the same query as you posted?

Comment: The query you say has the error can't be the right one since the table definition doesn't have the CustID column.

Comment: Sorry, changed attribute names for readability...and messed it up. Fixed.

Comment: I just copied and pasted the query from the stackoverflow window and it WORKS....I didn't know SQL took account of the formatting (the tabs? the spaces?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems when I was copying and pasting the statements from Workbench it was losing some of the spaces between keywords in the process. The pasted query appeared like this in command line:

```
SELECT CUSTNUM FROM(SELECT CUSTNUM, MAX(TOTALQTY) FROM(SELECT CUSTNUM, 
SUM(QTY) AS TOTALQTYFROM ORDERS GROUP BY CUSTNUM ORDER BY TOTALQTY DESC) 
ORDERS    ) ORDERS    ;
```

Note "TOTALQTYFROM", the error.

Lesson learned...don't mindlessly copy and paste, or at least check what I've pasted!

I'm leaving this post in case someone else has a similar issue.